# Accessing HTTP context in the exception handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

In my *Program.cs*, I invoke the general exception handling like this.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(Delegates.ExceptionOptions(app.Logger));
```

Then, in *Delegates.cs*, I have the following definition. Since I needed to access the HTTP context, I chose to rely on piggy-backing on the injected builder, running it with the context provided.

```
public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> ExceptionOptions(ILogger log) 
  => builder => 
  {
    builder.Run(async context =>
    {
      Exception exception = context.Features
        .Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!.Error;
      ...
    });
  };
```

I can't shake off the sensation that I'm over-complicating the approach. Is there a (non-hacky and non-sucky) way to access the context without actually invoking a run of the builder. (To be honest, I expected this to fail as I seemingly start running the app twice, since the builder has a second invocation of `app.Run()` at the end of the *Program.cs*.)

**edit**

The following doesn't enter the catch statement. Postman mentiones something about *set AllowStatusCode404Response to true*.

```
public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> ExceptionOptions2(ILogger log) =>
  builder => builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    try { await next.Invoke(context); }
    catch (Exception exception) { ... }
  });
```

Comment: Middleware is executed in order if registration. Perhaps try it as the last registered thing?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 I have it almost at the end. `app.UseExceptionHandler(Delegates.ExceptionOptions2(app.Logger)); app.MapControllers(); app.Run();` Or am I missing your point?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `UseExceptionHandler`, it boils down to middleware registration.

As a result, you can just do the following

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle your error
    }
}));
```

Comment: That is a correct statement. However, I can't figure out how it addresses the original question. Please help me understand.

Comment: Your question asks how to access the context, in my example the HttpContext is the first parameter in the `Use` call

Comment: My apology for not being clear enough. The thing I'm bothered by is if it's wise to actually invoke `builder.Run(async context =>...)` or if you could suggest an alternative approach not relying on executing `Run()` at all.

Comment: Like you mentioned, calling Run will have issues because the app is already running. What do you need to use `Run` for? Perhaps you could update your question for clarity & why `Use` won't work here

Comment: I updated the question. For some reason, the `catch` doesn't catch the error. It passes **outside** to the end of the lambda expression. Like if the actual exception doesn't happen there and the `next.Invoke(context)` actually works. Then, the exception is thrown (as it seems) afterwards. A bit confusing.